# Programmatically change start postion for animation

Tags: android, animation

In my Android app, I use an animation to slide a view up. My resource file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="1300"
        android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

and in code I execute the animation like this:

```
RelativeLayout rlMapContainer = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rlMapContainer);
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.map_anim_up);
rlMapContainer.startAnimation(animation);
```

I want to change the fromYDelta to a value that I determine at runtime. How can I change this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using xml file, you may try to animate view programatically.
Check my code which may help you for animation.

```
TranslateAnimation anim1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0,
                    500, 0);
            anim1.setDuration(500);
            anim1.setFillAfter(false);

            layTransparent.animate().setDuration(500)
                    .setListener(new AnimatorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    });

            layTransparent.startAnimation(anim1);
```

Comment: setFillAfter needs to be set to true.

Comment: In this example, your listener is not making any reference to anim1. I think the listener in this case should be defined like this:  anim1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {                       
                            }
                        });

Answer (score 0):

The following code accomplishes the same thing:

```
  TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 1200, 0);
  translateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
  translateAnimation.setDuration(800);
  translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
  rlMapContainer.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
```